# Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock not working

Tags: magento-1.9, stock-status

I have configured Magento 1.9 as shown in picture. **Display out of stock products** to YES, and **Qty for items status to become out of stock** 4

The problem is, even though the quantity of a product is below 4, it still show as in stock with green texts. what did I miss?

[image]

Comment: do you have more then one store ? if yes , please check store wise value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be due to your theme or your store settings.

If your theme doesn't handle stock status properly that could be causing that problem.

If these settings aren't on the proper store that could also be the cause of the issue.

I was able to get it to work with your exact settings.